# Docker Response code 500. Message: unknown error: cannot find chrome binary

Tags: java, docker, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was doing web scrapping using selenium java. I have the same version of chrome driver as my chrome browser and i have also set the binary path for chrome  in my code:

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
 options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");


 WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

The code in Springboot works fine, I built a docker image with Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:bullseye-slim

WORKDIR /app

EXPOSE 8081

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-17-jre-headless libnss3 libxcb1

COPY target/springboot-exe.jar /app/
COPY chromedriver.exe /app/

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/app/springboot-exe.jar"]
```

and when I run the docker image, I got the error no chrome binary:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 23051
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
[1700010675.161][SEVERE]: bind() failed: Cannot assign requested address (99)
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
Exception in thread "Thread-5" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: no chrome binary at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
Host info: host: '32d4e279bec7', ip: '172.17.0.2'
Build info: version: '4.8.3', revision: 'e5e76298c3'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.10.16.3-microsoft-standard-WSL2', java.version: '17.0.9'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], binary: C:\Program Files\Google\Chr..., extensions: []}}], desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], binary: C:\Program Files\Google\Chr..., extensions: []}}}]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:148)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:106)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:67)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:165)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:183)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:158)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:229)
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:157)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:101)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:88)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
        at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:73)
        at com.linggd.demo.Duldung.run(Duldung.java:54)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
```

My Chrome browser version is 119.0.6045.160 and
my chrome driver version is 119.0.6045.105.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker containers use a different filesystem layout to your main computer.

You wrote in your code,

```
options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
```

But chrome.exe does not exist inside the Docker container.

It will also not help to `COPY` your chrome.exe into the container, because Docker containers run Linux (Debian Linux in your case), and Linux cannot run exe files.

---

What you should do is use the package manager to install a copy of Chrome for the container to use. Here's what I did in my own Dockerfile to install dependencies:

```
RUN apt-get install -y wget libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libnss3 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libcups2 libdrm2 libxcomposite1 libxdamage1 libxfixes3 libxrandr2 libgbm1 libxkbcommon-x11-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libasound2
```

Then you can install a Linux version of Chrome by downloading and installing Chrome from its website into the container:

```
RUN wget -q https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get install -y ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

I personally had to run Chrome with the following command line arguments:

```
"--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox", "--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--remote-debugging-port=9222"
```

I assume Chrome gets installed on the `PATH`, so Java should be able to auto-detect the location of the Chrome binary without you having to `setBinary`.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I have updated my Dockerfile and the chrome binary error is fixed. I remain the setBinary() since I am not sure whether the Chrome is installed on the Path. When i run docker image, I got another error 'Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up 
 failure.' 'Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Timed out waiting for driver process to start.' I have tried to add those arguments you suggested and without them, but the error still exist.

Comment: I would suggest investigating why Chrome is not starting. You could do this by trying commands in a `docker exec` environment, or by searching "docker selenium chrome issues" online, or by opening a new question on SO.